# What parameter values does `in_timezone` accept?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I was working with time conversions in rails and tried [in_time_zone](https://apidock.com/rails/DateTime/in_time_zone) function.

```
Time.current.in_time_zone("Fiji")
```

The allowed parameters for the function are mentioned [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html). Out of curiosity, I also tried a couple of parameters that came to my mind.

```
Time.current.in_time_zone("EST") # worked
Time.current.in_time_zone("IST") # didn't work
```

Both the parameters weren't mentioned in the doc. Where can I get the full list of parameters that the function accepts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `TZInfo::Timezone.all_country_zone_identifiers`

You may also print all available zones with the below code:

```
TZInfo::Timezone.all.each do |zone|
 puts zone.identifier
end
```

You will notice that `EST` is available but not `IST`

Comment: `TZInfo::Timezone.all_country_zone_identifiers.any? { |a| a == "EST" }` returns false. So i think thats not the exhaustive list ?

Comment: @SojanVJose Updated the answer

Comment: Now you can do something like this `TZInfo::Timezone.all.map(&:identifier).any? { |a| a == "EST" }`

Comment: `TZInfo::Timezone.all_identifiers` makes it simpler i guess.